# Problem with Decorators and dynamic created List of Elements

Tags: zend-framework

I have a Problem with Zend Decorators. I try to reach a simple List.

```
<ul class="gallery" id="gallery">
  <li><img src="image1" /></li>
  <li><img src="image2" /></li>
</ul>
```

I create the Image List dynamically.

```
foreach ($imageData as $fileData)
{
  $filename = 'image'.$counter;
  $form->addElement('note',$filename);
  $form->getElement($filename)->setValue('<img src="/img/'.$fileData.'">')
       ->addDecorator('Label')
       ->addDecorator('Errors')
       ->addDecorator('HtmlTag', array('tag' => 'li'))
       ->addDecorator(array('ulTag'=>'HtmlTag'), array('tag'=>'ul','id' =>'gallery'))
  $counter++;
}
```

Unfortunatelly I am getting:

```
 <ul class="gallery" id="gallery">
   <li><img src="image1" /></li>
 </ul>
 <ul class="gallery" id="gallery">
   <li><img src="image2" /></li>
 </ul>
```

I don't understand, how I have to change the Decorators, to get all my Images in 1 List and not multiple ul tags. Can anyone give me an advice? Thanks a lot in advance !

Answer (score 0):

You can use [display groups](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.form.forms.html#zend.form.forms.displaygroups) to group the elements, then add the ulTag decorator to the group, not the individual elements.

The code below should be roughly what you need:

```
    foreach ($imageData as $fileData)
    {
      $filename = 'image'.$counter;
      $images[] = $filename;
      $form->addElement('note',$filename);
      $form->getElement($filename)->setValue('<img src="/img/'.$fileData.'">')
           ->addDecorator('Label')
           ->addDecorator('Errors')
           ->addDecorator('HtmlTag', array('tag' => 'li'))
      $counter++;
    }        
    $form->addDisplayGroup(
        $images,
        'images',
        array('disableLoadDefaultDecorators' => true)
    );
    $form->images
        ->addDecorator(array('ulTag'=>'HtmlTag'), array('tag'=>'ul','id' =>'gallery'))
```

Comment: I have tried this, but I also want to add an additional Item to the DisplayGroup which should than be outside of the List, but as soon I add the ulTag to the DisplayGroup it would include that Element aswell, I therefore thought that I have to first get my Elements set-up and after that add both to the DisplayGroup. I hope this makes sense...

Comment: What is this additional item?  And why does it need to be in the display group?  The display group is just to add the `<ul>` tags, so if you don't want the item in the list, leave it out of the display group.

Comment: The additional Item is a Trash Bin. I am trying to create a small Gallery where you can move your Image in a Trash when you want to delete it. I am using jQuery for this. You can find the Code here http://jqueryui.com/demos/droppable/#photo-manager . When you look for the Code, it shows that the List and the trash is in a Div, so my DisplayGroup needs to have a Div which include the Images in a List and a Trash Link in its own Div Container.

Comment: Ok, what you've tried and the answer I've given solves the main question you've asked - i.e. getting your `<li>`s in one `<ul>` list.  Re the 'demo' container div, I'm not sure that this is actually required?  If it is, my first thought was nested display groups, but it looks like this isn't possible.  It might be easier adding it with jQuery?  Alternatively, it looks like sub-forms might be the only option

Comment: Excatly my thought, nested displayGroup, but think this is not possible. Than I thought if I don't find a ZF solution, I will have to use jQuery. I don't really know if the outside div container is needed, but I would think it is. I will still have a look at Sub-Forms, maybe this is a solution as well. Thanks so far.